# Is there a function to generate random number using triangular distribution in c++?

Tags: c++, simulation, distribution

I'm searching for a function in c++ which i give it ( min , mode , max ) then it returns a random number generated by triangular distribution. If there is a code for implementing this function ,it will be so good.

Comment: Maybe [`std::piecewise_linear_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_linear_distribution) can do what you need?

Comment: thank you . But how can i use? @miles budnek

Comment: What do you mean by R function? Are you referring to the `R` language? Are you asking for a function in `C++` that is similar to a function available in `R`?

Comment: @JosephWood No i use R as the name of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::piecewise_linear_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_linear_distribution) can be used to model a triangular distribution.

Here's an example based on the sample code on the linked cppreference page that generates a triangular distribution that generates numbers between 0 and 30 with a peak at 20:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <map>

std::piecewise_linear_distribution<double> triangular_distribution(double min, double peak, double max)
{
    std::array<double, 3> i{min, peak, max};
    std::array<double, 3> w{0, 1, 0};
    return std::piecewise_linear_distribution<double>{i.begin(), i.end(), w.begin()};
}

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    // create a mersenne twister PRNG seeded from some implementation-defined random source
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    // create a triangular distribution with a minimum of 0, a peak at 20, and a maximum of 30
    auto dist = triangular_distribution(0, 20, 30);

    std::map<int, int> hist;

    // use our distribution to generate 10,000 random numbers
    // (truncated to integers for the sake of output; the generated numbers are actually real numbers)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        double num = dist(gen);
        ++hist[num];
    }

    // print out a nice histogram of the numbers generated
    for(auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << p.first << ' '
            << std::string(p.second/10,'*') << '\n';
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
00 **
01 *****
02 ******
03 ************
04 **************
05 ******************
06 **********************
07 *************************
08 **************************
09 *********************************
10 ************************************
11 **************************************
12 *************************************
13 ********************************************
14 **************************************************
15 **************************************************
16 *******************************************************
17 *******************************************************
18 ************************************************************
19 *****************************************************************
20 **************************************************************
21 *******************************************************
22 ************************************************
23 *******************************************
24 ***************************************
25 ******************************
26 **************************
27 ****************
28 ***********
29 ***
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sample from a *simple* triangle distribution *T* by summing two uniforms, *U₁* and *U₂*. In C terms this would be:

```
 float U1 = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
 float U2 = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
 float T  = U1 + U2;
```

*Scale accordingly*: the result is between 0 and 2 with a mode of 1.